# Problem with Windows 11 login & BitLocker on a laptop that needs a reinstall

Tags: windows, ntfs, bitlocker, parted

I got the laptop from a customer on Monday, back then it still ran, was on standby and logged in..
Then tried to backup the data to a SMB network share, but the laptop suddenly got lockups, so I needed to reboot.
After that the password didn't work anymore.

I booted with a PartedMagic boot cd, but was unable to mount because the windows drive was BitLocker.
She is 100% sure the password is right, but I never entered it myself.

Any idea how the data could be backupped?
Is there a chance it could only be a BitLocker partition, but the data in fact not encrypted?
How could I mount it then from a Linux live CD?

I would appreciate any advice, because such a case never happened to me...
but I'm not so up-to-date with Windows 10 & 11.. I didn't do many reinstalls with them..

- Login is so far impossible, because there is no USB key and no answers to the security questions.
- with a PartedMagic DVD booted and using "blkid" of "sfdisk" I see a BitLocker Partition but not a normal NTFS one
- tried to mount that partition but the filesystem can not be detected

Update:

I found [BitLockerUtility](https://github.com/cmartinezone/BitLockerUtility) and tried, it says it has no encrypted partition. So I suspect the NTFS could be just within that BitLocker Partition, at a specific offset.
GParted and Ubuntu installation both offer me to resize the "bitlocker" typed partition, but I don't dare to try because I fear them rendering it corrupt (there is a 1TB NTFS in it, and what if resize doesn't handle it properly?)

Answer (score 0):

Login to their live.com account
https://account.microsoft.com/devices/recoverykey

That will give you the recovery key. Then attach the hard drive as a secondary drive to your computer and put the recovery key in. Then copy off the data.

Or.put the recovery key into the place when you. Oot from DVD.

Comment: Good pointer so far. I hoped to avoid taking the disk out, also don't have any Win 10/11 system myself, I run Linux..
I'm trying WinPE boot DVDs, MiniTool/Easeus/Hiren's/Sergei Strelec.. the first has EFI, but fails anyway, the next 2 lacking EFI, trying the last one now.
Could you point me to a WinPE that is up to the job?

Comment: R-Studio (https://www.r-studio.com/Data_Recovery_Technician.shtml) has an option where you can install it onto a boot disk and then run the recovery software by booting it on the laptop. You should then be able to put in the recovery key once the diskk is recognized. Just remember to have another hard drive ready to copy the data to. DO NOT recover to the same disk.